# Mysql ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'abc'@'slave4' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, privileges

I am able to access server remotely with same credential

```
mysql --host="x.x.x.67" --user="abc" --password="xxyy" --database="dbname"
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 81480482
```

But when I am trying to write a file remotely its throwing an Error

```
 mysql --host="10.64.133.67" --user="abc" --password="xxyy" --database="dbname" -se "select * from dbname.param  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/abcd.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
 ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'abc'@'slave4' (using password: YES)
```

I am able to fire select query without any exception. I am totally lost that why am I getting an exception while writing

**INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/abcd.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'**

into tmp file.Thanks.

Files privileges worked for me:-

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'abc'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user misses FILE privilege.

Comment: "Azure Database for MariaDB" does not support OUTFILE, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/concepts-limits